# Increase performance when reading text file, parsing lines, and adding to database

Tags: performance, entity-framework, parsing

I'm tasked with reading up to 800k lines from a text file, parsing each line, then adding each line to a database. So far my solution only does 15 records per second. I'm looking for ways to speed this up. It basically opens the file, reads the next line, parses the data into an object that can be inserted into the database, then uses Unit Of Work and Repository patterns with Entity Framework to insert that object into the database. Then it goes to the next line of file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public ActionResult ReadFile()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/files/" + "itemmstrnew");
        ProductManager pm = new ProductManager();

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            pm.InsertProductByLine(line);              
            counter++;
        }
        file.Close();

        return View();
    }
```

InsertProductByLine

```
    public void InsertProductByLine(string line)
    {

        Product product = new Product();
        product.ProductID = "TUR" + line.Substring(0, 6).Trim();
        product.Description = line.Substring(6, 30).Trim();
        product.Status = line.Substring(36, 1);
        product.Hazardous = line.Substring(37, 1);
        product.StandardPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(line.Substring(38, 8));
        product.BestPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(line.Substring(46, 8));
        product.SellUOMID = line.Substring(54, 2);
        product.RetailPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(line.Substring(56, 8));
        product.RetailUOMID = line.Substring(64, 2);
        product.ConvFactor = Convert.ToInt16(line.Substring(66, 6));
        product.Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(line.Substring(72, 6));
        product.Length = Convert.ToDecimal(line.Substring(78, 6));
        product.Width = Convert.ToDecimal(line.Substring(84, 6));
        product.Height = Convert.ToDecimal(line.Substring(90, 6));
        product.Cube = Convert.ToDecimal(line.Substring(96, 6));
        product.SegmentID = line.Substring(102, 4).Trim();
        product.Category = line.Substring(106, 10).Trim();
        product.Subcategory = line.Substring(116, 30).Trim();
        product.Brand = line.Substring(146, 30).Trim();
        product.Model = line.Substring(176, 30).Trim();
        product.PrimaryColor = line.Substring(236, 6).Trim();
        product.SecondaryColor = line.Substring(242, 30).Trim();
        product.ColorPattern = line.Substring(272, 1);
        product.SizeGender = line.Substring(273, 1);
        product.Size = line.Substring(274, 20).Trim();
        product.SizeModifier = line.Substring(294, 1);
        product.VendorPartNo = line.Substring(295, 30).Trim();
        product.Application = line.Substring(325, 55).Trim();
        product.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;

        this.Insert(product);
        _UnitOfWork.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of going to database after parsing every line, you can use a list of objects to at least pass 100 records at a time this will reduce the database hits as well and increase the performance.

Comment: The majority of the elapsed time is almost certainly the cost of doing a database update. The cost of parsing the input will be negligible in comparison. Batched updates are normally a huge win.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the complete file once in memory and read line from memory buffer. Reading each line from database is not a good idea especially when there are high number of records.

Also check what is the maximum size of the file you may have at any time & how frequent is this operation, plus number of users performing this operation simultaneously.